# Space of operators on function

Tags: operator-theory, lie-algebras, operator-algebras

Consider the following space of operators on function of $n$-variables

$A= Span \{x_ix_j\ , x_i \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} , \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x_i \partial x_j} , i,j=1,2,\cdots,n\}$. Prove that $A$ is closed under the commutator operation $[a,b]=ab-ba$.

I have tried to computed the bracket $[,]$ for the three combinations in the generators of span, but i actually dont know what is meant by closed under the operation, can someone compute one of them for me as an example, thank in advance.

Comment: "Closed under the operation" means $[X, Y] \in A$ for $X, Y \in A$.

Comment: thank you robert, I have solved the problem partially, with only one case i cant resolve, namely $[x_ix_j, \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i \partial x_j}] \in A$. I have shown that $x_ix_j, \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i \partial x_j}]f(x_1, \cdots , x_n) = -(f + x_i \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i } + x_j \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_j }$) , then i cant go on anymore because i cant show that $A$ contains the identity, please helps, thank you so much

Comment: I have tried checking your calculation and it looks OK to me so far.  Are you sure $A$ isn't supposed to contain the constants?

Comment: oh I just asked the TA of the course and he said that $A$ should contain the identity, thank you for yoyr help so much Robert:).

Comment: My pleasure, glad to be of assistance in this matter!